# Create android apps for existing Website or Blog based on PHP

Tags: php, android, web-services, web, mobile-application

I just want to ask, How to create android apps for existing PHP website? In this case how to connect between android apps with my our existing database? I use MySQL database.

For example, android apps for stackoverflow. How we create like that?

Comment: You need to use webservice as in interface to access value from mysql. You can refer following link to see how webservice and android works

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: OK, thank you @Ravi I will check the link know.

Answer (score 0):

you need **web services** to connect your android app and your website or your database, from [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-tutorial/) you can learn how to do that.

If it helps, do check the answer as accepted...have fun, coding

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try the tutorial that you suggest to me. Thank you!

Comment: I would be wary of programmerguru.com - I've found [security problems](http://awooga.jondh.me.uk/report/33) with their material in the past.

Comment: thank you ...i din't knew that..still that tutorial has been really helpful